# How to cache introspect request on Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot to my resource server with OAuth2 authentication. But the authentication server (it's not ours) is getting instable and can't resolve sometimes.

I've already read many articles but couldn't find out how to cache these requests to reduce the amount of 401 on the app.

My security configuration is runnning like this:

```java
.oauth2ResourceServer()
                .opaqueToken()
                .introspectionClientCredentials(this.clientId, this.clientSecret) 
                .introspectionUri(this.introspectionUri);
```

Could someone help me?

PS: I tried to use `@Cacheable`, but I don't think I tried the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those running the same issue. Here is how i have solved:

Exposed the bean on my security configuration:

```
@Bean 
public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
    return new CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector(this.introspectionUri,this.clientId, this.clientSecret);
  }
```

And created a custom class to cache the values found:

```
public class CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
  private final OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector;

  private CacheManager cacheManager;
  private Cache<String, OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal> accessTokens;
CacheManager.createCache("iamCache",CacheManager.getRuntimeConfiguration);
  public CustomOpaqueTokenIntrospector(String uri, String clientId, String clientSecret) {

    cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder().build();
    cacheManager.init();

    accessTokens = cacheManager.createCache("iamCache",
        CacheConfigurationBuilder
            .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal.class,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1000))
            .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(1800))));

    this.introspector = new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector(uri, clientId, clientSecret);
  }

  public @Override OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
    if (this.accessTokens.containsKey(token)) {
      if (this.getAccessTokensCacheFromCacheManager().get(token).getAttribute("exp") != null
          && ((Instant) this.getAccessTokensCacheFromCacheManager().get(token).getAttribute("exp"))
              .isAfter(Instant.now())) {
        return this.getAccessTokensCacheFromCacheManager().get(token);
      }
      
      this.getAccessTokensCacheFromCacheManager().remove(token);
    }
    OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = introspector.introspect(token);
    this.getAccessTokensCacheFromCacheManager().put(token, principal);

    return principal;
  }

  public Cache<String, OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal> getAccessTokensCacheFromCacheManager() {
    return cacheManager.getCache("iamCache", String.class, OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal.class);
  }
}
```